# #NAME error when setting cell formula through VBA.

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am writing a macro that requires me to get the average of the values in a column with an unknown number of rows. I use this to get the number of the last row:

```
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
```

That works. What doesn't work is when I try to use it here:

```
Range("B2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE('table1'!AM2:AM" & lastRow & ")"
```

Doing that, I get a result of `#NAME?`. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4):

Change `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1` to `ActiveCell.Formula` since you're using basic A1 notation and not R1C1.